# what is the real version for "Apache/2.0.63 (Unix)" in a HTTP response header?

Tags: apache

I'm trying to install Apache with the version matching that of a specified server. Yet I'm stuck at finding the true version of the server given its HTTP response header:

Apache/2.0.63 (Unix) PHP/5.2.6 DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.0.63 OpenSSL/0.9.8

I've looked at the http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html but it does not match. Apparently either the server is running a really old version or Apache has changed the version numbering.

Can somebody please help me clarify this. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at two different things. Tomcat is a servlet container for Java servlets and JSP pages, not a general purpose HTTP server.

What you're looking for is the ["real" Apache HTTP server](http://httpd.apache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

G'day,

As an aside, that is an old version of Apache though it is the latest stable release for the 2.0 version of the server.

The version of the latest stable release is 2.2.14.

cheers,